# How should I convert my range receptacle?

Tags: electrical

My kitchen is equipped for  dual fuel range, with both gas and electric, with a 50A breaker, 6/3 + ground, and a corresponding receptacle to accommodate that wiring.

We are replacing our range with a gas unit, which only requires to be plugged into a "normal" nema 5-15p outlet.

How should I adapt my existing 6/3 wiring in the wall to serve this range? It seems incorrect to wire nut 12awg to the 6awg and replace the receptacle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you think is incorrect is exactly what I'd do and what I have done in the past. Ideal make a blue wire nut that would work for a #6 connected to a #12, Do that for one hot leg on both ends and the one end of the neutral where the outlet will go. Install a 15 Amp breaker and connect the #12 pigtail to it. connect the two pigtails at the box to your new outlet. Don't forget to connect the ground wire. Cover the box with the appropriate cover. You could also use split bolt connectors instead of wire nuts. Just make sure you have about a mile of electrical tape. Tape up the ends of the unused wire.

Comment: Install a 15a breaker on the jbox behind the range?

Comment: @Matthew in the main panel where the 50 AMP breaker is.

Comment: So replace the breaker, pigtail in the panel breaker>12>6, then at the range jbox 6>12>receptacle?

Comment: Yep. The neutral and ground in the panel will be ok as is.  At the range box, hot pigtail goes to brass screw and neutral pigtail goes to silver screw. Ground to ground screw on outlet, it might have to be pigtailed too.